# Get Roles specified on an action of a controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I have an MVC Controller and a class that creates a menu with items that must only be displayed to users with a specific role for an action of a controller. In the below case I don't want to display the menu item of Details to users with Role2. What I end up doing is to specify the same roles on the menu items, the same roles that I already specified on the controllers. So I have 2 places where I define the roles and they must be the same, so it's error prone.

What I would like to do is to get the roles from the controller somehow but I have no clue how to do it or if it's even possible.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Role1,Role2")]
public class MyController
{
    public IActionResult Index() 
    {
        return View();
    }

    [Authorize(Roles = "Role1")]
    public IActionResult Details(int? id) 
    {
        ...
        return View(...);
    }
}

public class MenuItem
{
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public string Controller { get; set; }
    public string Roles { get; set; }
}

...
var item = new MenuItem 
{ 
    Action = "Index", 
    Controller = "MyController", 
    Roles = "Role1,Role2",                                <---- this is what I do now.
    Roles = GetRoles(MyController.Index.AuthorizedRoles)  <---- this is what I need.
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this factory method for your `MenuItem`:

```
public class MenuItem
{
    public string Action { get; private set; }
    public string Controller { get; private set; }
    public string Roles { get; private set; }

    private MenuItem() { }

    public static MenuItem For<TMethod>(TMethod method) where TMethod : Delegate
    {
        var methodInfo = method.GetMethodInfo();
        var attributes = methodInfo
            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AuthorizeAttribute))
            .Cast<AuthorizeAttribute>();

        // If no attribute is defined on the action method, check the controller itself
        if (attributes.Count() == 0)
        {
            attributes = methodInfo.DeclaringType
                .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AuthorizeAttribute))
                .Cast<AuthorizeAttribute>();
        }

        return new MenuItem
        {
            Action = methodInfo.Name,
            Controller = methodInfo.DeclaringType.Name,
            Roles = string.Join(',', attributes.Select(a => a.Roles))
        };
    }
}
```

This can be called like:

```
var menuItem = MenuItem.For<Func<IActionResult>>(MyController.Details);
```

Comment: That's beautiful indeed, exactly what I was looking for. However, it's giving me an error: Argument 1: cannot convert 'method group' to 'Delegate'.

Comment: If I make MyController.Details static and change Delegate to Func<IActionResult>, then it compiles but I can't have static functions in MyController.

Comment: @fonZ Yes, I should have tested. Its a shame that methods can't be passed directly as delegates, but I've updated the answer for a generic way that will work, albeit not as clean. You could always change it to accept the method name as a string, but I'd prefer to keep the strong typing.

Comment: It still complains about the method not being static, it needs an object reference. And I agree, strong typing is better but instead of strings I could use e.g. nameof(MyController), nameof(MyController.Index). Can I create a Delegate from strings? Because if that's the case, then I can just do that before your For method.

Comment: Your answer solved my problem and gave me the insights I needed, thanks a lot. Sorry for not accepting your answer sooner.